# How to add support of marshmallow to existing pre Marshmallow Application

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

can any one knows how to add support of marshmallow to existing Application that application is pre marshmallow application? how to check permission at runtime or how to write code for checking permission at runtime. and where that code written in application?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please bother to comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For runtime permission, I have created this class which is universal and can be used from anywhere -

```
public class AppPermission {

    public static boolean isMarshmallowPlusDevice() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public static boolean isPermissionRequestRequired(Activity activity, @NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
        if (isMarshmallowPlusDevice() && permissions.length > 0) {
            List<String> newPermissionList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != activity.checkSelfPermission(permission)) {
                    newPermissionList.add(permission);
                }
            }
            if (newPermissionList.size() > 0) {
                activity.requestPermissions(newPermissionList.toArray(new String[newPermissionList.size()]), requestCode);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then put this code where you require permission from user-

```
if (!AppPermission.isPermissionRequestRequired(MyActivity.this, new String[]{"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"},
        REQUEST_APP_PERMISSION)) {
    // Your code if permission available
}
```

After this, in your `Fragment` or `Activity` put this code -

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_APP_PERMISSION:
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                String permission = permissions[i];
                int grantResult = grantResults[i];
                switch (permission) {
                    case "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS":
                        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResult) {
                            // Your code
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The above code is for request permission for `GET_ACCOUNTS` you can change it to whatever required.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official documentation for Marshmellow:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

As per this documentation, granting permission when used is a feature introduced in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) so I am afraid its not possible in previous versions.

However, if the the user uses a `CyanogenMod` or `MIUI` phone, there are apps which wrap the permission model of stock Android apps and make dynamic permissions possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
First check if the device is Android 6.0 by using below code

here is the example of read contacts

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){

// here check wheather runtime permission is granted or not 
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// ask for permission
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
} 
else 
return;
}
Don't forget to define permission in manifest fileYou can check permission in Home Screen  please follow the link below

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
```

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal